Upgrading Webpack with npm and Angular
This question follows my last one.
I am upgrading a legacy Node/Angular application (10 years old!) and have got everything compiled without error messages, etc. I am using an index.html folder at the server root to start off the application, through this code:
<body>
  <tc-app>Loading...</tc-app>
</body>

<tc-app> is a piece of Angular code. This invokes an app.component module, with the selector 'tc-app'. This in turn loads a template in the file "app.html", which in turn invokes yet further component modules, each with its own templates, and so it goes.
In the legacy application, using Webpack 1.15.0, Webpack generates three files for the /dist folder: app.bundle.js, app.css, vendor.bundle.js. The new application, using Webpack 5.94.0, happily generates app.bundle.js. However, it does NOT generate app.css. That is to be expected: the legacy application uses ExtractTextPlugin, now deprecated. However, my attempts to figure out how the replacement MiniCssExtractPlugin can be used to generate the app.css file in /dist have so far failed. Including the line
new MiniCssExtractPlugin("app.css"),

in the rules section of webpack.config.js generates an error. Omitting the parameter, thus new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), allows Webpack to finish, but does not generate anything in /dist.
The second problem is generating the correct bundle for all the Angular components, output in vendor.bundle.js by the legacy application. I am able to generate vendor.bundle.js in the new file with this code:
  entry: {
    app: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/boot.js'),
    vendor: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/app.component.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(clientRoot, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate(info) {
     return 'file:///${info.absoluteResourcePath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}';
   },
  },

However, loading the vendor.bundle.js file seems to fail. In the legacy application, the tag <tc-app> triggers the code in vendor.bundle.us and has the browser load the template file app.html, and it carries on from there. In the new application, the <tc-app> tag does not invoke app.component.js. as it should, and app.html is not loaded. This is despite app.component.js indeed being bundled in the new vendor.bundle.js file.
In the legacy file, the vendor.bundle.js was generated by this code, in the plug-ins array:
   new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
      chunks: ['app'],
      minChunks: function(module, count) {
        return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(clientRoot) === -1;
      }

However, in the new application this code returns errors:
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
 at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
 TypeError: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous (/Users/pmr906_1/venv/TCangular/tc/public/webpack.js:125:5)

Here is my current webpack.config.js:
var _ = require('lodash')
  , webpack = require('webpack')
  , ResolverPlugin = webpack.ResolverPlugin
  , ProvidePlugin = webpack.ProvidePlugin
  , IgnorePlugin = webpack.IgnorePlugin
//  , ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
  , path = require('path')
  , clientRoot = path.resolve(__dirname)
  , bowerRoot = path.resolve(clientRoot, '..', 'bower_components')
  , nodeRoot = path.resolve(clientRoot, '..', 'node_modules')
  , devtool = 'eval-source-map'
  , debug = true
  , MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
;

switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    devtool = '#source-map';
    debug = false;
    break;
  case 'development':
    devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    debug = true;
    break;
}

var config = {
  context: clientRoot,
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/boot.js'),
    vendor: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/app.component.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(clientRoot, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate(info) {
     return 'file:///${info.absoluteResourcePath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}';
   },
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    rxjs: 'Rx',
    lodash: '_',
    bson: 'bson',
    'codemirror/lib/codemirror': 'CodeMirror',
    'codemirror/mode/xml/xml': false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.png(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/jpg&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.jpg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/jpg&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/font-woff&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/font-woff&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/octet-stream&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/svg+xml&prefix=dist/"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
    //          javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            }, 
          },
        ],
      },
    ], /*,
    noParse: [
    ] */
  },
  resolve: {
 /*   root: [clientRoot], */
    modules: [clientRoot, 'web_modules', 'node_modules', 'bower_components', ],
    fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "path": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "stream": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "crypto-browserify": false, //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify 
      },
    alias: {
      bower: bowerRoot,
      node: nodeRoot,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
      chunks: ['app'],
      minChunks: function(module, count) {
        return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(clientRoot) === -1;
      }
      }), 
     new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), 
  ],
  devtool: devtool,
};

var compiler = webpack(config);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  compiler.watch({
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
  }, handleError);
} else {
 compiler.watch({
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
  }, handleError);
  //compiler.run(handleError);
}

Update
Examination of the browser error output shows an error in reading a module generated by this line in the module:
Mongoose = require('mongoose')

Several other modules requiring this module subsequently fail also. Something is amiss in the call to mongoose. I will investigate (mongoose has caused huge difficulties in this upgrade). I discovered I was using a very old mongo-connect tool; I replaced this by the much more recent connect-mongo. No change.

Are you sure you are using the right tags? angular should be used for Angular 2+, but it looks more like a question about AngularJS (v1)

I don't think that is the problem: angular seems to behaving correctly (though your point is strictly correct; I am using angular 1. However, see the addendum above. It looks like the problem is to do with Mongoose.

Solved half the problem! Turned out that the module with the line
Mongoose = require('mongoose')

actually did not require mongoose so I just cut out that line, pressed npm start, rebuilt the /dist folder, and it all worked!!! I don't understand why other modules are able to include this line don't fail too, but they don't. So all good.
However, the other half of the problem, involving MiniCssExtractPlugin, still does not work. So I'll ask a question just about that one, if I cannot find a solution on the web.

I am hesitant to recommend a third question on the same problem, as it results in several questions each with a partial answer. If there is any way you can add an update to your existing question, it may be worth repurposing the post. I would not suggest that if someone else had answered, as it would invalidate their work, but since that is not the case, sticking with the same question may be the best approach.

It is worth noting that the aim of Stack Overflow is to produce Q&A documentation that is likely to be useful to future readers. If it is also useful as a personal "rubber duck" that is not a bad side-effect, but that is not the purpose of the site.

Good points. I am not asking the extra question, in fact. I'm having some other issues with npm now, which I will make the basis of another question. Thanks for the clarification. StackOverflow is a fantastic resource and I'd like to be a good citizen on here.

Great stuff, thank you
